# Is there a way to convert Corel Draw files from version 11 to X3?

Tags: software-recommendation, corel-draw, file-format

Is there a way to convert [Corel Draw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CorelDRAW) version 11 files to version X3 files?

I have files in Corel Draw 11 to be converted to the X3 version.

Comment: Did you try importing (instead of opening) the 11 file with X3? It is however posible to convert .cdr to .eps

Answer (score 2):

You simply open it in a newer version of Corel Draw, next time you save it it will be saved as this new version.

This way you preserve the layers, objects, groups, efects, etc.

---

I am adding this part sometime later because some people keep asking this variation: What if I do not have this new version?

If you do not have a newer version... you do not need a newer version.

I am asuming sometimes a client want a specific version. For example "the ultimate latest version".

You do not need to do anithing. He can just open the file and that is it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be in menu `File -> Save As` if you're trying to save down:

[image: Screenshot]

If you are trying to save to a **newer** version you would have to export out as an `.eps` file and import that in and do a `Save As`.

Personally and from experience it is easier to save out as an `.eps` or `.tiff` in CorelDraw unless you are trying to use the scale options.

Comment: Why the downvote?